# Why doesn't checkbox validation work in Parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, parsley.js

I can't for the life of me get Parsley.js to validate my checkboxes, even though my code looks just like their example. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='button-row'>
  <input data-parsley-mincheck='1' id='add-package-a-pre' name='add-package-alerts' type='checkbox' value='pre'>
  <label for='add-package-a-pre'>
    Pakke registrert
  </label>
  <input id='add-package-a-sent' name='add-package-alerts' type='checkbox' value='sent'>
  <label for='add-package-a-sent'>
    Pakke sendt
  </label>
  <input id='add-package-a-ready' name='add-package-alerts' type='checkbox' value='ready'>
  <label for='add-package-a-ready'>
    Pakke klar for henting
  </label>
  <input id='add-package-a-loaded' name='add-package-alerts' type='checkbox' value='loaded'>
  <label for='add-package-a-loaded'>
    Pakke lastet opp for utkjøring
  </label>
  <input id='add-package-a-delivered' name='add-package-alerts' type='checkbox' value='delivered'>
  <label for='add-package-a-delivered'>
    Pakke leveret
  </label>
</div>
```

Parsley works out of the box and prevents my form from submitting when I have an error in one of my text inputs, but it completely ignores the fact that none of my checkboxes are checked. As far as I can see, my code looks just like the example they provide: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

[I have also made a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/gyuxLkjb/)

Can anybody see why it's not working? I've been stuck on this for hours now, and I can't find anybody else who's experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out that Parsley will **always** accept that **no checkboxes are checked** as long as the `required` attribute is not set, even if `data-parsley-checkmin="1"` is.

To elaborate:

- `<input type="checkbox" data-parsley-checkmin="1" />`
  Will always pass validation, *no matter what*
- `<input type="checkbox" data-parsley-checkmin="2" />`
  Will only fail validation if 1 checkbox is checked
- `<input type="checkbox" data-parsley-checkmin="1" required />`
  Will fail validation if no checkboxes are checked

In other words, `data-parsley-checkmin="1"` is never useful. Just replace it with `required`.

Comment: That's correct, and should definitely be clearer in the docs. PR welcome.

Comment: If the "name" attribute isn't present, validation will pass